# Editing response content in Django middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware

I have Django 1.10 project and the following user-defined middleware

```
class RequestLogMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response.data['detail'] = 'I have been edited'
        return response
```

and a REST-endpoint view:

```
def r_mobile_call_log(request):
    return Response({'success': True, 
                     'detail': 'Before having been edited'}, 
                      status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So I would expect the final response on client-side to be:

```
{'success': 'True', 'detail': 'I have been edited'}
```

However, what I see is:

```
{'success': 'True', 'detail': 'Before having been edited'}
```

I put a breakpoint in the middleware's **call**  method to make sure that the function really is executed, and it's ok. `response.data["details"]` just won't change it's value. Anyone knows what's the reason for this ?

Answer (score 25):

`Response` is already rendered in the middleware stage so you can't just change `response.data`, you need to rerender it or change rendered content directly.

```
class RequestLogMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if isinstance(response, Response):
            response.data['detail'] = 'I have been edited'
            # you need to change private attribute `_is_render` 
            # to call render second time
            response._is_rendered = False 
            response.render()
        return response
```

The second approach is to change content directly, but in that case builtin REST Framework browser API will not work because template will not render properly.

```
import json

class RequestLogMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if isinstance(response, Response):
            response.data['detail'] = 'I have been edited'
            response.content = json.dumps(response.data)
        return response
```

[source code for render method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4696078832f486ba63f0783a0795294b3d80d862/django/template/response.py#L97)

Comment: `ValueError at ________`
`Circular reference detected`

Answer (score 11):

I don't suggest editing REST-Framework's Response with using middleware. I think you should overload REST-Framework's default JSONRenderer.

**Define a custom renderer:**

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer


class CustomJsonRender(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):

        if renderer_context:
            response = renderer_context['response']
            msg = "OK"
            code = response.status_code
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                msg = data.pop('msg', msg)
                code = data.pop('code', code)
                data = data.pop('data', data)
            if code != 200 and data:
                msg = data.pop('detail', 'failed')
            response.status_code = 200
            res = {
                'code': code,
                'msg': msg,
                'data': data,
            }
            return super().render(res, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
        else:
            return super().render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

**Using it in you APiVIew or ViewSet:**

```py
class SimpleView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (CustomJsonRender,)
    def get(self, request):
        # do something
        return Response({"id":"xx"})

class SimpleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = (CustomJsonRender,)
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
```

**You can edit it golbal in settings as well:**

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": ("compent.renders.CustomJsonRender",)
}
```

**Then your response has been changed.**

Comment: And the reason for this preference? Just easier to intercept b4 render i suppose ....

Answer (score 6):

I have a feeling that I found cleaner solution. Here's how I rewrote the code:

```
class RequestLogMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
       response = self.get_response(request)
       return response

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
       if hasattr(response, 'data'): 
          response.data['detail'] = 'bla-bla-bla'
       return response
```

Comment: `ValueError at ________`
`Circular reference detected` How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    response = self.get_response(request)

    res = str(response.content)

    res += "<h2>add some html!</h2>"

    response.content = bytes(res, encoding="UTF8")

    return response
```

**response.content** type is **bytes**, so you need first convert it to **str**,

add something to it, convert it to bytes

and finally assign it to the response.content.