# Django - Add extra data to response in middleware

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I've a middleware. I want to update the response object inside the middleware. Here is how I'm doing it.

```
class ErrorMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if 'errors' in response.data:
            response.data.update({'success': False})
        print(response.data) 
        return response
```

It prints the correct response, but what the client receives, is without `success` field. What am I missing?

Here is my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'modules.utils.middleware.ErrorMiddleware'
]
```

Comment: Do you use Django rest framework?

Comment: Yes. I'm using DRF.

Comment: I think this answers your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119275/4436641

Comment: @RieljunLiguid - It worked. Thanks a lot. :)